# Query: dept name with highest no of emps , error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

List the name of dept where highest no of emps are working

**Table**

```
emp_id   dname
1        D1
2        D2
3        D1
4        D2
5        D2
6        D3
7        D2
```

**Query**

```
select dname from emp_demo e1 having 
count(emp_id) = 
(select max(count(emp_id)) from emp_demo e2 
 group by dname )
```

**Error**

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

**Expected output**

D1 has 2 employees in it, D2 has 4 employees and D3 has 1 employee in it. So we should get department number D2 since it has maximum number of employees in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select dname
from (select dname, dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seq
      from table t
      group by dname
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

`DENSE_RANK()` will return one or more dept which are having highest same no_of_employee's.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `top (1)` and `group by`:

```
select top (1) dname
from emp_demo
group by dname
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `count()` function in the following manner.

```
; WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT dname
        ,count(emp_id) AS TotEmpCount
    FROM EmpDept
    GROUP BY dname
    )
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM cte
ORDER BY TotEmpCount DESC
```

[image]

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72e00bdc183ebdef0707acbbc0dd5b06) demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below simple query.

```
select dname, max(count(1)) from emp_demo
group by dname;
```